# Changing layout extension in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, layout

Can we change extension of layout files from phtml to php in ZF ?

How ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to add the following line into your `application.ini`:

```
resources.layout.viewSuffix = "php"
```

Another way would be by specifying the new extension in your `bootstrap.php`, e.g.:

```
public function _initLayoutExtension() {
    $layout = $this->bootstrap('layout')->getResource('layout');
    $layout->setViewSuffix('php');
}
```